# Unexpected pandoc behavior converting markdown list to html

Tags: pandoc

Pandoc describes its behavior clearly [here](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#pandocs-markdown) in the section "Compact and loose lists"

However the conversion of

```
# Test

- Item 1

- Item 2
  - Subitem 1
  - Subitem 2
```

results in

```
<h1 id="test">Test</h1>
<ul>
<li><p>Item 1</p></li>
<li><p>Item 2</p>
<ul>
<li>Subitem 1</li>
<li>Subitem 2</li>
</ul></li>
</ul>
```

My understanding is that the output should be

```
<h1 id="test">Test</h1>
<ul>
<li><p>Item 1</p></li>
<li>Item 2
<ul>
<li>Subitem 1</li>
<li>Subitem 2</li>
</ul></li>
</ul>
```

I'm using pandoc 2.10.1. Any thoughts?

Comment: The expected behavior was there for pandoc 2.3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was changed in pandoc 2.7 in order to get pandoc's behavior more in line with that of CommonMark. The changelog contains this entry:

> - Markdown reader:
>
>   - Improve tight/loose list handling (#5285). Previously the
>     algorithm allowed list items with a mix of Para and Plain, which
>     is never wanted.

The mentioned issue is [#5285](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/5285).

It seems that the documentation was not updated. This should be [reported](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/new).

Comment: Thanks! I just reported it [here](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/6684)